# how do I copy an .iso file to root in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, root-filesystem

How can i copy an .iso file to the root directory in Ubuntu? 
Unetbootin cannot detect my ubuntu.iso unless it will be moved to the root. 
When I attempt to move it, into the root, the system tells me I do not have permissions.
How can i assign permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the directory `/root`, right?

How about you execute the file manager Nautilus with root permission (`sudo nautilus`) and copy you iso where you need it? But be careful using Nautilus as root!

Maybe you should ask a different question... Do you actually want to write that iso to usb drive, or so? Why not using Disk Writer, Gnome's native tool, or `dd`?

Answer (score 0):

Case A: your target directory is "/root" and your file is called file.iso

in a shell (Terminal), run

```
 sudo cp file.iso /root
```

Case B: your target directory is "/" and your file is called file.iso

in a shell (Terminal), run

```
 sudo cp file.iso /
```

In either case, enter your password when prompted.